# Accessing HTML data attribute on-click via .data() doesn't work

Tags: html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

On click of one of the options I am trying to get the data value from the 'ul li a' and place it into button below, I've set up a JS fiddle example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/q5j8z/4/

But cant seem to get it working

```js
$('ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).data();
    $('.button').data('value');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a data-value="50" href="#">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-value="40" href="#">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-value="10" href="#">Option 3</a></li>
</ul>

<a data-value="" class="button" href="">Go</a>
```

Does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: see this modified fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q5j8z/16/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('ul li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).data('value');
    $('.button').data('value', value);
    console.log($('.button').data('value'));
});
```

Here, `$(this).data('value')` is used to get the `data` attribute value of the link.

and `$('.button').data('value', value)` is used to set the `data` attribute value of the button.

Using, `console.log($('.button').data('value'));` you can check the console the `data` value being set.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5j8z/11/)

For more info:- [.data() API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this:

```
var value = $(this).data('value');
```

And then:

```
$('.button').data('value', value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('ul li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var value = $(this).data('value');

        $('.button').data('value', value);
    });
```

You can see the value of the button with console.log into your console with:

```
console.log('data: '+$(".button").data("value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the value data to the button actually. Try this:

```
$('ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var value = $(this).data();

    // assign the value form the clicked anchor to button value data
    $('.button').data('value', value);

    console.log($('.button').data('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you are are you trying to insert the value of variable `value` or 'value' literal?

`data()` is meant to be used similarily to `attr('attr-name', attr_value)` like below:

```
$('ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    var value = $(this).data('value');
    $('.button').data('value', value);
});
```

The above works in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify a data- prefix because jQuery does that automatically.

So ensure you are using the right attribute for the value, as below:

```
$('ul li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $(this).data('value');
    $('.button').data('value', value);
});
```